# PendingIntent and DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-download-manager, notificationmanager

Is there any way to set up a PendingIntent with the download manager? Or the DownloadManager.Request? I'm sending the user a notification in the toolbar about the download with this:

```
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
```

request is initialized lik this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
```

I need it so that when the user clicks this notification they are brought to and activity or where the file was downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676786/how-to-launch-download-manager-from-broadcast-receiver).

That is, watch for [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED) and [ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) actions.

If you need more control you could use your own notification, updating it with your PendingIntent when the download is complete.